# punteros y arreglos de strings

Tags: c

Estoy teniendo problemas con mi código porque cuando aumento en 1 un puntero para imprimir varias strings, en lugar de imprimir la siguiente, se imprime la primera y se quitan caracteres.
Según lo que sabia, se imprime el
valor guardado en la dirección que tiene el puntero asi: `*puntero`, pero si lo pongo así en este caso no imprime nada.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (){
int i,n;
char strings[5][500],*p;
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf("Palabra #%d :",i+1);
    scanf(" %s",&strings[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf("%s     direccion de memoria %d\n",p,p);
 p+=1;

   
  }
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No me queda clara la pregunta. Lo que sí veo es que nunca le das un valor a la variable `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Varios errores en este código:

**n no está definida**

¿Cuántas veces se supone que se va a repetir el array?

```
int n;
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
```

Como esto tiene pinta de ser una errata que has cometido al pegar el código aquí, no entro en más detalles. Tu sabes cómo debes incializar esta variable.

**Te sobra una llave de cierre**

Tu programa tiene un número asimétrico de llaves de apertura y de cierre. Se ve un poco mal porque el código no está tabulado, no te sugiero escribir código no tabulado.

Tal y como está ahora mismo el código de la pregunta, la instrucción `return 0` está **fuera** de la función `main`

**p no está inicializada**

Aquí ya empezamos a entrar en detalles más serios. Imagino que tu idea aquí es usar `p` para iterar por la colección de cadenas ... pero no vas a conseguirlo tal y como está el código.

El motivo es que los arrays no funcionan exactamente igual que los punteros.

En un array los elementos se encuentran dispuestos en posiciones contiguas de memoria. Así, un array tal que:

```
char array[2][5] = {"hola", "chao"};
```

En memoria se organizará así:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a
 h  o  l  a \0  c  h  a  o \0 ....
```

Para poder apuntar a `hola` y a `chao` con `p` tendrías que incrementarlo manualmente 5 posiciones:

```
p = array;
puts(p);
p+=5;
puts(p);
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ElS7YDKs5VXY6raH)

La solución usando `p` se dería la siguiente:

```
char *p = strings;
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%s     direccion de memoria %p\n",p,p);
    p += 500;
}
```

Esto no es estético ni práctico, la gracia de usar un puntero es que para pasar de un elemento a otro simplemente tuvieses que incrementar el puntero en `+1`.

Sin embargo no necesitas `p` para imprimir las cadenas, podrías usar `strings` directamente. Un ejemplo:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%s     direccion de memoria %p\n",strings[i],strings[i]);
}
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias, y sí, esa era mi idea, para practicar los punteros ya que se viene un examen y no nos hann explicado aún.